# How to calculate network I/O throughput?

Tags: linux, networking

The following is the formula which I am using to calculate the Network I/O throughput :

```
Network I/O throughput =  (number_of_bytes_transmitted+received)/(time_spent)
```

The value for fields number_of_bytes_transmitted and number_of_bytes_received is retrieved by parsing the file `/proc/net/dev`

Sample Output(truncated) :

> `Interface |   Receive            |  Transmit`
>   `.         | bytes    packets     | bytes    packets`
>   `eth0      | 85775472   149166    | 13399430  121977`

So, number_of_bytes_transmitted = 85775472
and number_of_bytes_received = 13399430

Now, for the field 'time_spent'. I believe it is the total time spent in transmitting and receiving the bytes, like if there are two points say A and B, time_spent should be

```
                                  (bytes)

                       A -------------------------> B

                        <-------------------------
                              (time taken)
```

Is it correct? And if it is, then how to determine this value?

Also, is there some other better way to calculate the network I/O throughput of a KVM host,than the formula I mentioned above?

I have thoroughly searched on the internet, but could not find a solution.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.